# How to uninstall PacketTracer

Tags: uninstall, cisco

I installed cisco packettracer for networking class today, but I have no idea how I would go about uninstalling it. I have tried searching Synaptic Package Manager for terms like `packettracer`, `packet tracer`, `pt`, but nothing found.

To install I used the following script included in the `tar.gz` (which functioned for the install). This is the content and might give us an idea of how to do this...

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12413899/

How would I go about uninstalling it and cleaning it from my system?

Comment: Since this is a custom installer script, you need to consult the documentation about possible deinstallation methods. Software packages often contain `INSTALLING` or `README` files to such extent. I would take a peek, but I don't even know, what yo look for. Can you post a link to the software archive or its documentation?

Answer (score 7):

The application is installed in `/opt/pt` and the installer has created an desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop` and an icon. Therefore

```
sudo rm -r /opt/pt
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt6.png
```

---

Additionally, some packages have been installed:

```
lib32z1
lib32ncurses5
lib32bz2-1.0
libgcc1:i386
libstdc++6:i386
libssl-dev:i386
libqtwebkit4:i386
libqt4-scripttools:i386
```

Therefore you could try to remove the packages, but that is not absolutely necessary.

1. `sudo apt-get purge lib32z1`

   Check the output and **don't proceed**, if other packages will be removed which are ***not** in the list above.*
2. `sudo apt-get purge lib32ncurses5`

   Check the output and **don't** proceed, if other packages to be removed which are ***not** in the list above.*
3. Repeat step 2 for all other packages in the list above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using latest version, there is an available bash script to uninstall it.

```
/opt/pt/uninstall.sh
```

Here is the content of that file.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/packettracer


# check /etc/profile for existance of PT7HOME
PROFILE="/etc/profile" 

# error exit if file does not exist or unreadable
if [ ! -f $PROFILE ]; then
   exit 1
elif [ ! -r $PROFILE ]; then
   exit 2
fi

# read contents
exec 3<&0
exec 0<$PROFILE
while IFS= read -r line
do
  PT7HOME_FOUND=`expr match "$line" 'PT7HOME'`
  if [ $PT7HOME_FOUND -gt 0 ]; then
    continue
  fi

  QT_FOUND=`expr match "$line" 'QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO'`
  if [ $QT_FOUND -gt 0 ]; then
    continue
  fi

  EXPORT_FOUND=`expr match "$line" 'export PT7HOME'`
  if [ $EXPORT_FOUND -gt 0 ]; then
    continue
  fi

  EXPORT_QT_FOUND=`expr match "$line" 'export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO'`
  if [ $EXPORT_QT_FOUND -gt 0 ]; then
    continue
  fi

  CONTENTS="$CONTENTS\n$line"
done
exec 0<&3

sudo echo -e "$CONTENTS" > /etc/profile

exit 0
```